# Can't update document data with mongoose, node.js, express and async function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

I'm trying to make a login function that receives and email and password from user.

1. checks if email exists - works
2. checks if password match to encrypted password in db - works
3. if 1+2 is true -> generates a token and set the token into the user document. But it doesn't work, the action user.token = token is invalid, and postman yields no response.

what am I doing wrong?

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const User = require('../models/user');

exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;

        let emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                return res.json({ isAuth: false, message: 'Login failed, email not found' });
            }
            return user;
        });

        let isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, emailExist.password);

        if (!isPasswordMatch) {
            return res.json({ isAuth: false, message: 'Login failed, wrong password' });
        }

        let loadedUser = await User.findOne({ email: email, password: emailExist.password })
            .then(user => {
                if (!user) {
                    return res.json({ isAuth: false, message: 'Login failed' });
                }
                return user;
            })
            .then(user => {
                const token = jwt.sign({ role: user.role, email: user.email, userId: user._id.toString() }, 'secret');
                console.log(user);

                user.token = token;
                return user.save();
            });

        res.status(200)
            .cookie(('auth', token))
            .json({ isAuth: true, token: token, user: loadedUser });
    };
```

updated version: (still doesn't work)
now it gives me the following error:

> (node:11336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to
>   number failed for value
>   "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjowLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFoQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInVzZXJJZCI6IjVjMTc4NDc3Mzg5MWI5MjY5MGNkMzgwNiIsImlhdCI6MTU0NTA1MTY5OX0.8GWuV82A7yOvKKkXeOjIeYve5aH0YwBEK_RuH0NVfYA"
>   at path "token"

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    let emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: email });

    if (!emailExist) {
        return res.json({ isAuth: false, message: 'Login failed, email not found' });
    }

    let isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, emailExist.password);

    if (!isPasswordMatch) {
        return res.json({ isAuth: false, message: 'Login failed, wrong password' });
    }

    let loadedUser = await User.findOne({ email: email, password: emailExist.password });

    let token = jwt.sign(
        {
            role: loadedUser.role,
            email: loadedUser.email,
            userId: loadedUser._id.toString()
        },
        'secret'
    );

    console.log('token === ', token);
    console.log('user before token === ', loadedUser);

    updateUserToken = await loadedUser.update({ $set: { token: token } });

    console.log('user === ', loadedUser);

    res.status(200)
        .cookie(('auth', token))
        .json({ isAuth: true, token: token, user: updateUserToken });
};
```

Comment: dont use await and then together its a bad practice. after that you can debug it clearly.

Comment: @karina what is the output you get from console.log(user);
after the line const token = jwt.sign({ role: user.role, email: user.email, userId: user._id.toString() }, 'secret');

Comment: I get the user data, with the default token value set to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your user model file and see whether you have add the token as a number. if so this might be the issue. Try changing it to **string**

Comment: Thank you! you're right, it was defined as a number at the model. It works now.